# After final round, recruiter changes interview process and asks 7 days take-home asessment

Tags: interviewing, recruiting, assessment

As the title says. The company is a very big tech company (largest in the country) well founded unicorn.

First I applied, regular HR interviews. Then I was asked to do a 3 days extenuating take-home assessment. Then wait... wait wait... come back to me say fine, reviewed and will schedule technical interview with engineering managers. Do interview, wait... feedback ok, say explicitly next interview is FINAL round with CTO. Discuss salary per email, ok.

Take interview with CTO, short interview 1 hour, not technical, ok. Then silent for 1 and a half weeks.

Now the recruiter just sent an email, saying that they will move me forward to the 'next stage' and informs me that they are revamping their recruiting process so they are asking me to do an extra 7 DAYS take-home assessment and present it in a subsequent 1.5 hours interview.

Now wondering, how should I proceed?

- a) I shut up and comply, and follow up with their new assessment.
- b) I mention I have been holding back an offer of another company cause I was expecting the offer or rejection of this company to come soon, so now I need to rethink what to do
- c) I blank them
- d) I tell them I do not wanna continue the process

Other ideas? I do want the job, but, I wonder, how can I set my boundaries? i.e. if the keep me asking me to do assessments for the rest of the year, will I? I.e. how can I apply for a job and make effort during the process yet setting my boundaries and being respected?

Comment: `7 DAYS take-home assessment`.. after all the process has been completed, this is bit too much, IMHO.

Comment: Yes... I think the same. I am not happy about this.

Comment: Random idea. Make sure whatever you turn in has your copyright statement on it (and have witnessed copy in your files). "I'll be delighted to sign the copyright over to you once aim being paid. Until then, if we aren't in a contract, this is personal work _not_ done for hire and may be used only for the purpose of evaluating my application." Though honestly, the threat of mining applicants for work hours has always struck me as exaggerated and if I actually wanted the job I might not bother guarding against it.

Comment: "Discuss salary per email, ok." It sounds to me like this may be a stalling tactic. Maybe they offered the job to someone else and are waiting to hear back from them.

Comment: @keshlam makes totally sense. Or even better, I can ask if they are ok if I make it public in my GitHub. If they do not want me to make it public, then they need to pay for it.

Comment: Can you clarify the 7-day part ? What is the scope? Is it 7 work days (which would be insane) or a moderate assignment and they just give 7 days of time since you still have a day job ?"

Comment: d) - definitely d).

Comment: Do you think this company wants you to do **FREE** work from them by giving you this assignment ? Does this assignment look like a real small task that some developers may work on in a sprint ?

Answer (score 7):

Quote them your consulting rate for 7 days worth of work to proceed.

I'm not being entirely insincere here. Some hiring fields have a reputation for unscrupulous employers to ask for work to be done as part of a hiring process, which is, in effect, getting someone to do actual work for free.

IMO - You've already done a practical demonstration of your work, 3 days to me seems excessive - but that depends on the field you are in etc. I would also look very carefully to see if it looks to be a real request or just a hypothetical. The more 'Real' it looks, the more I would be standing firm on my demand for payment. The more abstract and hypothetical it looks, the more leniency I would give it.

e.g. 'I want you to come up with a marketing portfolio for *legit product* by *company we work with*' = Pay me my freelance consulting rate.

'I want you to come up with a marketing portfolio for blodgets by the company widgets' = less skeptical.

I would also ask the recruiter what information they are seeking to get from a 7 day work assignment that they didn't get from the 3 day work assignment.

Comment: I was thinking the same. It makes sense. However, I am equally sure this would mean they won't move forward with me. However, this would very well set my boundaries.

Comment: And also makes sense, to ask more details about the 7 days assessment. I might comfront them - how is that gonna be different from the 3 days one + the two interviews I did...

Comment: @Worker - I would start with the latter with the recruiter - if they insist on the 7 day assessment, then I would ask something like "Okay, can I get a PO and who I will be invoicing this **work** to?' - then if they push back - point out that they are asking for a total of 2 business weeks' worth of work *in total* - and that this work should be compensated for.

Answer (score 6):

After all the process has been completed, a *"7 DAYS take-home assessment"* is bit too much. It's very very unusual, it appears they are trying to get free work done by you (borderline scam, if I may add).

I'd advise, instead of a direct refusal to proceed with the process, please ask them to compensate for the time you need to put to get that task completed. That way, you put the ball in their court, and also verify whether this is actually a test or an attempted scam. If they are really interested in hiring you, and have noticed value in you, in the process so far, they'll be happy to compensate you, as you complete the task and show the value.

That said, I'd also advise, if you have other opportunities lined up, focus on them first. At this moment, this does not look like it's going to end on a positive note, and focusing only on this oppertunity may not get you the result you want. All the best.

Comment: It is a very big tech company (largest in the country) well founded unicorn valued over 1 billion USD.

Comment: @Worker good to know, but that changes nothing, unfortunately. People with unprofessional mindset can be found just about everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely unreasonable. Just tell them that you are still interested in the job, but you won't be completing their *7-DAY* (!) take-home assessment. If that disqualifies you, then it is their loss.